# Nhibernate with 2 front end servers, any issues with this out of the box?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, scalability

If I have 2 front end servers accessing a single db server, how will nhibernate operate in this scenerio?

Are there any things to watch out for?

Will running things using stateless sessions help?

Comment: you are the hero man! you have got over 11K reputations and so far answered only 6 questions. Do not take it otherwise. I thought the only way to get good reputation is by answering other's questions. Turns out asking quality questions also make you rich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make use of the [second level cache](http://ayende.com/blog/1550/deep-diving-into-nhibernate-the-second-level-cache), you'll need to select a provider that allows for distributed usage, such as the Memcached one.

To address the second part of your question, the [stateless session](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/10/08/statelesssession-nhibernate-without-first-level-cache/) only ignores the first level cache, so you won't need to worry about those.

Answer (score 1):

This is no different then a single web front end accessing the db.  You'll just have normal concurrency issues to deal with.  If two people edit the same record at the same time.. that kind of thing.